# Wordpress - Read In HTML Email Template Stored In a File

Tags: php, wordpress, html-email

From my custom theme in Wordpress, I'd like to send an HTML email.

**Rather than populating the body like this:**

```
$message = "";
$message = "<h3>Someone has applied for a job on the site.</h3>" . "<br><br>";
$message .= "Profile Picture URL: " . $Picture . "<br>";
$message .= "Name: " . $Name . "<br>";
$message .= "Email: " . $Email . "<br>";
$message .= "Phone: " . $Phone . "<br>";
$message .= "Work Phone: " . $WorkPhone . "<br>";
$message .= "Resume: " . $Resume . "<br>";
$message .= "Preferences: " . sanitize_text_field($Preferences) . "<br><br>";
```

**Instead,** I'd like the HTML email template to be it's own file.

Then, I want to read in the HTML Email template file and populate parts of it with some data stored in php variables.

So, let's say I have an html file:

**emailtemplate.html**

```
<h3>Name: [NameGoesHere]</h3>
<h3>Address: [AddressGoesHere]</h3>
```

Then, in my php file I have:

```
$name = "Jane Doe";
$address = "123 Street";
$message = "";
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);
```

How do I read that html file in, put the name and address where it goes, and then store it in $message?

My example seems too simple, but I've actually built 3 very thorough HTML emails that I want to use and it's a lot of code each.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `str_replace`.

First you would want to grab the template content as a variable

```
$template = file_get_contents('/path/to/your/template.html');
```

Then you need to swap in the existing variables for the placement markers. From your example source, you could then swap the name field in like this:

```
$template = str_replace('[NameGoesHere]', $name, $template);
```

Repeat as necessary for whatever content needs replacing.

Then when you are done, just use the result as your email content.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best own-written solution will just be to parse it using `php` built-in methods.

To read the file, use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

**Example**:

```
// From Link
<?php
// <= PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./HTML_TEMPLATE1.html', true);
// > PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./HTML_TEMPLATE1.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
?>
```

To parse the html file, use [the explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

**I suggest you put a delimiter which is ## for example** (see how this helps you later on)
  that will hold the place for the actual string.

```
<?php
// Example
// Use previous $file-> ($file  = "<html>...";)

$pieces = explode("#", $file);// "#" is YOUR_DELIMITER
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
?>
```

Then, fill the odd/even indexs of the array (depends on how you parse it).

**if you parse it with # as I suggested, you will have a bunch of empty items that you will want to fill in with the values from the php code - just iterate the array and set them. You can create an array from all values you want to insert and then it will be even easier**,

and then re-attach array to a string, and thenset it to `$message` using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

**Simple example from link:**

```
<?php

$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
?>
```

And then, set it back to `$message` and mail:

```
$message = $value_of_attached_array;
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);
```

Hope this helps :)